# slide up and slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have one list with groups name.

```
<ul id="groups" >
  <li id="group1" ></li>
  <li id="group2" ></li>
  <li id="group3"></li>
</ul>
```

and sliding containers

```
 <div id="containers" >
    <ul id="container1" >
      Lorem ipsum ..
    </ul>

    <ul id="container2" >
          Lorem ipsum ..
        </ul>

    <ul id="container3" >
          Lorem ipsum ..
        </ul>
  </div>
```

What I want to do is when you click on group it is hidding existing container and showing new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hideAll() {
    $("#container1 #containter2 #container3").hide();
}

$("#group1").click(function(){
    hideAll();
    $("#container1").show();
}

$("#group2").click(function(){
    hideAll();
    $("#container2").show();
}

$("#group3").click(function(){
    hideAll();
    $("#container3").show();
}
```

Fast and brutal but might work if you have a small number of elements.  If you have a lot more, then you should break things into classes (`$(".container").hide();`), etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#groups > *").live('click', function() {
    var linkIndex=parseInt($(this).attr('id').match(/[0-9]+/)[0], 10);
    $("#containers > *").slideUp('slow');
    $("#containers > *").filter(function() {
        var containerIndex=parseInt($(this).attr('id').match(/[0-9]+/)[0], 10);
        return containerIndex==linkIndex;
    }).slideDown('slow');
});
```

**You can demo a (slightly modified) version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jv6fV/).**

Comment: I just realized I could probably have used [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq), but this should work too.